# Reconstruct multidimensional array data php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
$array = array(array("1" => "a",
                        "2" => "hello a1",
                        "3" => "ab",
                        "4" => "ab1",
                        "5" => "hello ab1"),
                array("1" => "a",
                        "2" => "hello a1",
                        "3" => "ab",
                        "4" => "ab2",
                        "5" => "hello ab2"),
                array("1" => "a",
                        "2" => "hello a1",
                        "3" => "ac",
                        "4" => "ac2",
                        "5" => "hello ac2"),
                array("1" => "b",
                        "2" => "hello b1",
                        "3" => "bb",
                        "4" => "bb1",
                        "5" => "hello bb1"),
                array("1" => "b",
                        "2" => "hello b1",
                        "3" => "bb",
                        "4" => "bb2",
                        "5" => "hello bb2"),
                array("1" => "b",
                        "2" => "hello b1",
                        "3" => "bc",
                        "4" => "bc3",
                        "5" => "hello bc3"),
        );
```

I want to get this output

```
$final = array(array("1" => "a",
                        "2" => "hello a1",
                        "3" => array(array("1a" =>  "ab",
                                            "2a" => array(array("1b" => "ab1",
                                                                "2b" => "hello ab1"),
                                                            array("1b" => "ab2",
                                                                    "2b" => "hello ab2")
                                        ),
                                    array("1a" =>  "ac",
                                            "2a" => array(array("1b" => "ac2",
                                                                "2b" => "hello ac2")
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                array("1" => "b",
                        "2" => "hello b1",
                        "3" => array(array("1a" =>  "bb",
                                            "2a" => array(array("1b" => "bb1",
                                                                "2b" => "hello bb1"),
                                                            array("1b" => "bb2",
                                                                    "2b" => "hello bb2")
                                        ),
                                    array("1a" =>  "bc",
                                            "2a" => array(array("1b" => "bc3",
                                                                "2b" => "hello bc3")
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                    );
```

As you can see the parent values are a and b. Sub-parents are ab, ac, bb, bc.
Children are ab1, ab2, ac2, bb1, bb2, bc3. I want to match the array by:
parent -> sub-parent -> child

Answer (score 0):

you can get simple like this

```
foreach ($array as $key) {
 foreach ($key as $value) {
   echo $value;
   echo "<br>";
 }
}
```

Comment: I want to reconstruct my array